# Merge two hashes on a particular value

Tags: ruby

I am checking whether the hash `hash_volumes` below has a key whose `instance_id` matches with a key of hash `hash_instance`.

```
hash_volumes = {
  :"vol-d16d12b8" => {
        :instance_id => "i-4e4ba679",
    },
}
hash_instance = {
  :"i-4e4ba679" => {
        :arch => "x86_64",
    },
}
```

If it does, then I need to merge it to the `hash_instance`. I find that `vol-d16d12b8` matches with the instance `i-4e4ba679` and hence I want to merge it with `hash_instance` so that the final `hash_instance` will look like below:

```
hash_instance = {
  :"i-4e4ba679" => {
        :arch => "x86_64",
        :volume => "vol-d16d12b8"  # this is new entry to `hash_instance`
    },
}
```

I am not able to merge these two hashes as explained above. I suspect my `if` statement is wrong. Please take a look at my code below:

```
hash_volumes.each_key do |x|
  hash_instance.each_key do |y|
    if hash_volumes[x][:instance_id] == y  ## I think this line is the problem
      hash_instance[y][:volume] = x
    end
  end
end

hash_instance
```

Output:

```
{
    :"i-4e4ba679" => {
        :arch => "x86_64"
    }
}
```

The code above gives `hash_instance` without adding `volume` to it. I tried as below, but none worked:

```
if hash_volumes[x][:instance_id] == "#{y}"
# => this if statement gives me syntax error
```

.....

```
if hash_volumes[x][:instance_id] =~ /"#{y}"/
# => this if statement does not make any changes to above output.
```

Comment: @sawa, Thanks for point it out. I have edited the code. I always make typo while preparing a test code for posting on SO.

Comment: Good. Now I will remove repetition to make your question concise.

Comment: you need to convert strings to symbols or symbols to strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash_volumes = {
  :"vol-d16d12b8" => {
        :instance_id => "i-4e4ba679",
    },
}

hash_instance = {
  :"i-4e4ba679" => {
        :arch => "x86_64",
    },
}

hash_volumes.each do |key, val|
  id = val[:instance_id]  #returns nil if the there is no :instance_id key

  if id 
    id_as_sym = id.to_sym

    if hash_instance.has_key? id_as_sym
      hash_instance[id_as_sym][:volume] = id
    end
  end
end


--output:--
{:"i-4e4ba679"=>{:arch=>"x86_64", :volume=>"i-4e4ba679"}}
```

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, find() has to search through the keys every time. Doing one hash lookup, e.g. calling include?()/has_key?() is much more efficient than searching through the keys. In addition, I would avoid using unless at all costs--it's an abomination. Finally, 'compact' usually means 'very hard to read', and certainly doesn't mean more efficient, and as a result should not be emulated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation would be this:

```
hash_instance.each do |k1, v1|
  next unless k = hash_volumes.find{|k2, v2| v2[:instance_id].to_sym == k1}
  v1[:volume] = k.first
end
```

Comment: Thanks. this is concise and compact solution.

Comment: ...and many not work.  v2[:instance_id] will return nil if v2 does not have such a key, and then nil.to_sym will throw an error.  If hash_volumes can have entries like: `:googly => { :hello => "goodbye" }`, then that solution needs to be altered.

Comment: @7stud I assumed that `:instance_id` is always there as a general format. That is my interpretation.